# Best Python IDE on Linux

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Can anybody suggest me good Python IDE for Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Answer (score 21):

Probably the new [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html) from the makers of IntelliJ and ReSharper.

Comment: It should be noted that it's not free.

Comment: Free community edition is available

Comment: In the installation instructions it is written "Copy the pycharm-5.0.4.tar.gz to the desired installation location". What installation location would you recommend? just in a folder of my home directory? Ups, I found some information here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Installing+PyCharm+on+Linux+according+to+FHS

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan He was probably referring to it as a "non-free software" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software

Answer (score 8):

I haven't played around with it much but eclipse/pydev feels nice.